# Core Bluetooth Discovering Services: device connected, but received error "not connected"

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, core-bluetooth

I'm working with a Bluetooth Device, in detail I need to:

- connect
- discover services
- discover characteristics
- get some data
- disconnect

It is done continuously and works perfectly, except that after few minutes I start receiving strange results, since the  `peripheral:didDiscoverServices:` gives me these logs:

```
Peripheral state: 2
Error: Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=3 "The specified device is not connected." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The specified device is not connected.}
```

Code used to get the logs:

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"Peripheral state: %li", (long)peripheral.stat);
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

I tried to check for race conditions, but all the callbacks are received on the same queue and only 1 operation is active (next one is started after disconnecting successfully).

Reading [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1518744-peripheral), it is possible to receive an error in case something goes wrong, but how can the Peripheral be in the **Connected** AND **Not Connected** state at the same time?

My idea:

- My device has something wrong.
- There is an internal limit in the CB component in the way it handle requests
- Bug in the CB
- It's perfectly fine, but not well documented (in this case, how to handle it)

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Are you getting the data from the same peripheral each time? If yes, then why not just stay connnected. Have you implemented the `didDisconnect` and `didFailToConnect` delegate methods?

Comment: Hi Paulw11, yeah I get data from the same device each time and unfortunately I can't stay connected - request from high level :). Implemented, and the `didDisconnect` get called only after the `peripheral:didDiscoverServices:` is called - but it's called because I disconnect each time.